# Remove XDocument node by id

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Hopefully this will be an easy one for someone to fix.

I am removing xml nodes using the following code.

```
    XDocument XD = XDocument.Parse(content);
    XD.Root.Descendants("{http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}rect").Remove();
```

This works fine but I am now wanting to do a where clause on the rect to remove only the  nodes with the id of "bpr". I've seen a few examples including .Where but this doesn't seem to want to work with my code.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: "this doesn't seem to want to work with my code" - that's not a terribly precise description of what goes wrong. Please provide a short but complete example with a sample input XML file and expected output, as well as the code.

Comment: Hi Jon, sorry, I should have said. It was flagging up .Where in VS2010 because I didn't include a ref to using System.Linq; But now i'm getting an error in regards to using Foo42's example. The code within .Contains is flagging up with the error message -  "cannot convert lambda expression to type System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute because it is not a delegate type"

Comment: Have suggested a change to Foo42's answer, as well as providing my own simpler (IMO) one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler alternative (IMO) to Foo42's answer:

```
XDocument XD = XDocument.Parse(content);
XD.Root.Descendants("{http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}rect")
       .Where(el => (string) el.Attribute("id") == "bpr")
       .Remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
XDocument XD = XDocument.Parse(content);
    XD.Root.Descendants("{http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}rect").Where(el => el.Attributes().Contains(at => at.Name == "id" && at.Value == "bpr")).Remove();
```

I think something like this should work

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm trying to test it but i'm getting an error in VS2010. It is underlining 'at => at.Name == "id" && at.Value == "bpr"' with the error message - "cannot convert lambda expression to type System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute because it is not a delegate type"

Comment: I think you want `Any` instead of `Contains`