# How to remove node from xml with XDocument class in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-xml

just,I tried to remove the node from the xml file  what i have.But it is showing exception. the below code what i tried.

```
 LoadXmlFile.Element("NewElementName").Remove();            
 LoadXmlFile.Save(@"D:\yyy_RemoveElement.xml");
```

It is showing exception like "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."

Comment: It would help if you could include the text of the exception and indicate specifically which line raised the exception.

Comment: I assume the `Element` call is returning null as no matching node was found, resulting in a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: It is showing exception like "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove XDocument node by id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9634290/remove-xdocument-node-by-id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this.it will help you well.

```
 LoadXmlFile.Descendants("NewElementName").Remove();         
 LoadXmlFile.Save(@"D:\yyy_RemoveElement.xml");
```